# On Symfony2, how to retrieve in a RequestListener the allowed HTTP Methods of the called route?

Tags: rest, symfony, symfony-2.1

All is in the title,

I'd like in a RequestListener to retrieve the HTTP `@Method({"GET", "POST"})` allowed in the annotations for the current called Action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get `router` service in your listener and pass current route name `$_route` into your listener action.

And then you'll be able to get requirements for current route:

```
...
yourListenerAction(..., $_route)
{
    ...

    $collection = $router->getRouteCollection();
    $route = $collection->get($_route);
    $requirements = $route->getRequirements();

    $methods = $requirements['_method']; //will return string "GET|POST"

    ...
```